# Give an example of subset which is not a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be an abelian group with Identity $e$. Let $H$ be a subset of $G$ such that each of its elements square is the identity element.

We now prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$: Clearly $e \in H$ since $e^2=e$. Also if $a \in H$ then $(a^{-1})^2=e$ which implies that inverse of each element of $H$ will be in $H$. There is one more thing to show - closure, to do that we observe that for any $a$ and $b$ in $H$, $(ab)^2= (ab)(ab)= a(ba)b = a(ab)b =(aa)(bb)=e$ . So the operation is closed in $H$.

It is a good observation to make note how the condition- $G$ is Abelian  helped us to prove that $H$ is a subgroup.

Now what if $G$ is not Abelian?

A quick search yields an example of non Abelian group which doesn't satisfy this condition. If we consider $G$ as set of all $2 \times2$ matrices with nonzero determinant is sufficient to show this. Although I didn't prove it, I believe that if $G$ is any group of $n \times n$ matrices with nonzero determinant, then $H$ will not be a subgroup of $G$.

Is there any group which is non isomorphic to these group of matrices such that $H$ is not a subgroup?

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: I'm confused, are you saying 1. if $a\in H$ then $a^2 = e$ or 2. if $a^2 = e$ then $a\in H$ or both?

Comment: If $a$ is there in $H$ then $a$ will be there in $G$, since $G$ is group $a$ will have inverse. Here I'm proving that inverse of $a$ will be there in $H$.

Comment: You want to prove that in the non abelian group of $2\times 2$ non singular matrix, the subset of the matrix $A$ such that $A^2=I_2$ is not a subgroup. Right?

Comment: No, I'm interested in finding a group which is non isomorphic to these group of nonsingular matrices such that $H$ is not a subgroup. @Raffaele

Comment: In $S_3$ the subset of elements such that $\sigma^2 = 1$ is the set of all transpositions together with the identity, which is not a subgroup. Your matrix group is not clearly defined enough for me to compare.

Comment: Under your current definition of $H$ "a subset of $G$ such that each of its elements square is the identity element", then it is not true that $H$ is a subgroup. (Just take $G$ to be the Klein group and let $H$ contain two of the three involutions.) To make the conclusion true, you should change to "Let $H$ be THE subset of all elements of $G$ that square to the identity."

Comment: Think about how your proof works. You prove that $ab$ squares to the identity, and you want to conclude that $ab\in H$. You only know this if all such elements are in $H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Try the smallest nonabelian group: the dihedral group of order $6$.

---

*NB:* This group is isomorphic to the subgroup of ${\rm GL}_2(\Bbb Z)$ generated by $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix},$$ so it might not be in the spirit of your question.

---

> Let $H$ be the subset of all flips of the equilateral triangle.